# Using ReactiveOAuth with Windows Phone 7, to access Dropbox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am building an application which requires accessing Dropbox. Since there is no api for windows phone yet, i am using the ReactiveOAuth to achieve this.

I was referring to this tutorial, http://blogs.developpeur.org/kookiz/archive/2011/11/13/wp7-upload-a-file-to-dropbox-using-reactiveoauth-wp7.aspx.

I have followed all the steps, but VS shows an error saying

> Error 1   'DropBoxTest.MainPage' does not contain a definition for
>   'RequestToken' and no extension method 'RequestToken' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'DropBoxTest.MainPage' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have added all the mentioned classes and references. Could anyone please have a look and help?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look to Spring.NET Dropbox.
It supports WP7 and provides a sample too.
http://www.springframework.net/social-dropbox/